# Replace do_action() with a normal submit form in comments.php

Tags: comments

In my comments.php I have this code:

```
 <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" tabindex="5" value="Submit" />
 <?php comment_id_fields(); ?>
 <?php do_action('comment_form', $post->ID); ?>
```

Is there a way to replace this code whit a simple submit form? and not use: do_action() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php comment_form(); ?>
```

**References:**

- [Function Reference for `comment_form();` on WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_form)
- [`comment_form();` WordPress function reference, arguments and source at QueryPosts](http://queryposts.com/function/comment_form/)